# initramfs ubunto alongside windows10

Tags: lubuntu

hi can any one help me to find my mount command (The mount command may be different for you)

mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /root -o force

they sed To find out your exact command reboot, select Ubuntu and press Esc when you see the countdown.

Choose to enter in recovery mode. but after I dont know how to find it. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi I have fond solution , super easy just click E from Keyboard whan boot count statr (means edit) aftr it show you screen go to second last line in it's end just tipe nomodeset ...after press Ctrl+x means (save and exit).
so you login fast